# Share composable in nav host

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a NavHost which hosts multiple composables from the main screen to the login screen as show below:

```
@Composable
fun Navigation() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = Screen.Main.route) {
        composable(route = Screen.Main.route) {
            StatusBar()
            Main()
        }
        composable(route = Screen.Login.route) {
            StatusBar()
            Login()
        }
    }
}
```

You see how the Status bar is in both `Main` and `Login` composables I was just wondering if it would be possible to define it in one place so it can be used across all composables?

Comment: Why don't you use StatusBar inside Main and Login?

Answer (score 0):

To keep your code clean I would recommend using the `StatusBar` in `Main` and `Login`. Because at the end the `StatusBar` and its state belongs to the screen and not to the `NavHost`.

The problem is that your screen is the component which owns all the information that the StatusBar needs (even though there are no parameters; this is theoretical representation). So it makes sense that the Screen owns its sate.

The composable of the `NavHost` on the otherside only knows the curren screen, but none of its state unless you state hoist it in a very ugly way. So it makes sense that it only holds that state it is best in managing.

Because of the fact that you already have put the `StatusBar` into an composable you also don't have a problem with code duplication.